# Changing media specific CSS properties from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media

I have a CSS property (font) that I need to be able to change from Javascript (a pulldown). However, this font should only be used when printing (@media print).

So, the javascript can't just change the value of the font, because that will effect the screen view as well. Is there a way to change ONLY the print version of the font property?

Alternatively is there a way to have a CSS property be a reference to another property?

That way, in the print CSS, I could say font:printfont, and in the screen CSS font:12. And then change the value of printfont, and it would only change the font when printing.

thanks.

EDIT: The point is that I need to be able to change the font size that the document gets printed at from the pulldown, but I don't want to change the font size that the document gets displayed at.

Answer (score 10):

That's an interesting dilemma you have going on there. Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think of is to add a new  tag to the header where your font-size is declared with !important. For example, in your head tags:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

.printfont {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

</style>
```

This will ensure that the new font-size will take precedence.

The following is a very quick example of how you may accomplish this with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var inlineMediaStyle = null;

    function changeMediaStyle ()
    {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
        newStyle.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        newStyle.setAttribute('media', 'print');
        newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode('.printFont { font-size: 16px !important;}'));

        if (inlineMediaStyle != null)
        {
            head.replaceChild(newStyle, inlineMediaStyle)
        }
        else
        {
            head.appendChild(newStyle);
        }
        inlineMediaStyle = newStyle;
    }

</script>
```

Just ensure that you have onchange="changeMediaStyle()" as an attribute on your dropdown. Also, as a disclaimer in my example, I am not accounting for things like memory leaks, so you will have to work out those kind of issues on your own.

As to your alternate question, as far as I am aware, there isn't any method for declaring/using what is essentially CSS variables. However, there is currently a recommendation out there for it: http://disruptive-innovations.com/zoo/cssvariables/

Comment: But then how do I change that from the javascript in the pulldown?

Comment: Don't add on the server-side, then on the first change from the pulldown, use Javascript to add it to the dom and keep a reference to it. If the user changes the value (pulldown) again, remove it from the dom, and re-add it with the updated value(s).

Comment: But how do I (in javascript) remove or add a property only in the @media print case?

Comment: +1 Kudos for using JavaScript (and not jQuery), as requested.

Answer (score 3):

seems like what you want to do is myabe just change or add a class to the item with JS

```
<p class="inrto comicSans">this is the text to change</p>

@screen p.intro {font-family:verdana;}

@print p.comicSans {font-family:comic-sans;}
```

Comment: I don't understand this suggestion. I need to change the font (size, but that doesn't matter) at UI time. So, I want the user to be able to use a drop down to change the size, and then when you print, it uses that size.

Comment: if its case of font size then i assume you have a finite number of options. delcare them as values of a series of class's and then apply that class name to your body tag... the same notation that i described above

.largeFont {font-size:1.5em;}
.mediumFont {font-size:1em:}

add these classes to your body (of course this will only work if they are relative and not fixed!)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use JavaScript to switch classes, and have the

```
@print {
  .myPrintClass { font-family: serif; }
}
@screen {
  .defaultClass { font-family: sans-serif; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the class-based solutions would totally work, you could also use Javascript to dynamically add a new `<link>` tag to the page.  For instance, if you have:

stylesheet1.css:

```
@print * {font-family:verdana;}
```

stylesheet2.css:

```
@print * {font-family:comicSans;}
```

You could then use jQuery to do something like:

```
$(document.body).append("<link href='stylesheet2.css'/>");
```

(you could do it without jQuery too, but I forget that syntax and am too lazy to look it up ;-)).

However, if you're only changing small amounts, a single stylesheet + different classes is probably the better way to go; the new `<link>` tag solution is only worthwhile if you have a bunch of different style changes happening.

Comment: I'm currently using the classed based solution. the problem is that I can't change any values on the fly!